# Moving from Nitra syntax to Antlr4

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I am moving custom grammar from Nitra to Antlr4. As I haven't found any resources on my own, I am asking you what *recommendations, resources, possible tools* could be suggested for this syntax migration?

Comment: could you be more specific on *completely different beast*. Because at the first sight both syntaxes looked similar:
Nitra: 
`syntax ExpressionOperator =  '$' operation
{
 regex operation = "add" | "sub" | "div" | "mul";
}`
and antlr:
`additionExp
    :    multiplyExp 
         ( '+' multiplyExp 
         | '-' multiplyExp
         )* 
    ;`

Comment: Haha, I looked at https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/11/12/an-introduction-to-nitra/ thought the Gherkin snippet was Nitra. OK, perhaps they are similar, but my recommendation remains the same: learn some ANTLR, see: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4#useful-information